# Fault analysis- per unit query

Tags: circuit-analysis, fault

im trying to do fault analysis on image 1. I was little confused for the line as there wasnt a j component so unsure how to find the pu.

In images 2 and 3 show a line with R+jX and the R id disregarded for the calculation. Could someone explain what do do for image 1 case. Thanks

[image: image1][image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzhfW.png)
[image: image 3]

Comment: Yes, the “X=“ infers that the line is all inductance with no resistance.  Add the j and party on.

Comment: as i have example of X=10.89/ph going to 1j so what would X=15.89... thanks

Comment: think i understand. can i message you on discord or email

Comment: The 10.89/ph simple means each phase is j10.89 ohm.  So, the positive sequence impedance of the line is j10.89 ohm.